# How to Create option is not working in Odoo 16

Tags: python, xml, view, hide, odoo-16

I have the following code, but only no_open works and no_create does not work, I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

```
 <field name="requested_by" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="requested_by" readonly="1"/>
<field name="requested_by" create="0"/>
<field name="requested_by" create="false"/>
```

try one of these

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).